# Не получается инициализировать камеру в Android

Tags: java, android, камера

Работаю с Android (Java). Не получается инициализировать камеру.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

`open()` - выделяет красным и не может инициализировать. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [работа с камерой Android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475352/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-android)

Comment: Когда вы мышкой наводите на строчку с ошибкой - что IDE говорит об ошибке?

Comment: Пишет Cannot resolve method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю вы сделали импорт класса `Camera` для 3d преобразований.

А вам нужнен `import android.hardware.Camera;`

Comment: Да спасибо! На самом деле не тот импорт... Я даже не мог подумать(

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что в манифесте присутствует следующее:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: оо спасибо, действительно я не указал пермишены, но проблема осталась(( open(); - подчеркивает красным(( Пишет Cannot resolve method...